# При наведении на блок меняется положение других блоков?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При наведении на красный квадрат, желтый уходит и появляется серый. Нужно чтобы можно было наводить на серый, когда курсор убирается с красного. А если на серый не наводят, то обратно появляется желтый квадрат. Не могу понять как это правильно реализовать. https://jsfiddle.net/n39ueco8/39/

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text");
let content1 = document.querySelector(".content1");
let content2 = document.querySelector(".content2");
function serviceshoverMenu() {
    text.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            content1.classList.add("_active");
        }, 600);
        content2.classList.add("_active");
    });
    content2.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            content1.classList.add("_active");
        }, 1600);
        content2.classList.add("_active");
    });
    content2.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            content1.classList.remove("_active");
        }, 400);
    });
    text.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            content1.classList.remove("_active");
        }, 400);
    });
}


serviceshoverMenu();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.content1 {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content1._active {
 display: none;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content2._active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
     <div class="content1"></div>
     <div class="content2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее описать вопрос? Просто инчего не понятно O_o

Comment: Тоже не понимаю, но вроде автор имеет ввиду если мышь убирать с серой коробки то она обратно желтой должна стать

Comment: @tiptop98 объясните людям что вы хотите?)

Comment: если мышь убирать с серой коробки то она обратно желтой должна стать + если убрать с красной коробки, то серый тоже желтый должен стать, если на серый не навели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял я задачу или нет, но я попытался вам помочь, вот что у меня получилось

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".text");
  const content1 = document.querySelector(".content1");
  const content2 = document.querySelector(".content2");

  text.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
    content1.classList.toggle("_active");
    content2.classList.toggle("_active");
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }

  .text {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
    background-color: red;
  }

  .content {
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
  }

  .contents{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .block{
    position: absolute;
    transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .content1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    right: 0;
  }

  ._active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .content2 {
    background-color: grey;
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="block content1 _active"></div>
      <div class="block content2"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, это и нужно) спасибо)